# Spring boot, freemarker. Resources not retrieved 'because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type '

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I have a spring boot app configured to deliver freemarker template views. I wanted to return json data for some ajax calls but when I added the configuration, the resources stopped working. It stated that they were json objects and would not be loaded as css, and later on the error 
"Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/resources/css/common.css' because its MIME type ('') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 ()"

My config:
[image: config file]

[image: negotiator config]

[image: security config]

How can this be solved? I followed the following: 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml

And got nowhere.

Comment: I have just seen that http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.min.css is being handled by the controller with the following mapping:@GetMapping(name = "/notifications/count.json")

Comment: Please don't post code as images, but rather use text with proper code tags. Why all the configuration? Spring Boot already configures that for you. Just follow the Spring Boot conventions and things will work. Also `/webapp/resources` doesn't exist as `/webapp` isn't part of the application (it will be removed). Basically you are trying working around the framework in stead of working with the framework.